# visual studio can't find packages automatically

Tags: visual-studio, installation

while trying to install visual studio enterprise 2015, it keeps telling me "a setup package is either missing or damaged" and tells me to either find the package manually, ignore it or download it. the packages are in the program's setup folder, but it doesn't install them automatically and even if I choose one of the packages from the packages folder and then the program starts to install the next package, it opens the "browse" windows to the "temp" folder in the C driver and I have to browse all the way again to the next package, as the program files are in a whole different driver. And it doesn't ignore or download the packages when I tell it to. Does that mean the setup file is damaged or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, can you successfully install the VS 2015 using the ISO images now? If this issue persists, please update it in here.

Answer (score 1):

Please view the document: [UPDATE: SHA-1 signed content to be retired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/sha-1-signed-content-retired).

• On April 26, 2021, Visual Studio 2015 and older web installer files were removed from the Microsoft Download Center. These products can be installed from ISO images available at [Downloads - Visual Studio Subscriptions Portal](https://my.visualstudio.com/downloads).

To install the VS enterprise 2015, please try to access the above Downloads and sign in with your Microsoft account, search 'Visual Studio Enterprise 2015' or 'Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3'(the latest version) and click 'Download' to download the DVD (ISO images), the ISO images includes all installation resources and use it to install.